# Adaptive Card dropdown field with multi-select option

Tags: botframework, chatbot, adaptive-cards, bot-framework-composer

Can we have dropdown in Adaptive card with multi-select option?

We need to display list of users in a dropdown and let the end user to select multiple users from the dropdown displayed.

We are using composer based bot with .Net SDK for bot development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Input.ChoiceSet](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Input.ChoiceSet.html). You can use the [designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/) to get it laid out the way you wish.

- and use the isMultiSelect option.